# Class with functions that extends more than one implementation of the same data structure. Can be done?

Tags: class, kotlin, data-structures

I'm studying Data Structures in my CS course.
University professor assigned us a project where we have to implement every data structure from 0 without using the already one provided by the programming language we choosed to use.

All of this is required for pass his lab part of the exam:

- For every data structure we have to develop more than one known implementations.

  ```
   An istance : For the List data structure
                We have to develop ArrayList, LinkedList and DoubleLinkedList in separate 
                classes and packages.
  ```
- We have to follow the known formal specifications.

  ```
   An istance : For the List class
                We can only declare "data structure releated" members and attributes
                Like create,delete,head,isEmpty,isLast,next,previous,insert,write,read,remove
  ```

I completed those ones, but

I need to put "services functions" in a separated class/file for every Data Structure and it should work for every class(implementation) of them.

then following the istances above:

I have to develop a class/file named "ListServices" that should "extend" every class like:
MyArrayList
MyLinkedList
MyDoubleLinkedList

For Services I mean "not needed" functions for the data structures like:

`printList() //it prints the whole list`

`goToList(position : Int) //goes to the position using Integers`

`sortList(whichsort : String, order : String) //whichsort = quicksort,mergesort and order ascending/descending`

`purgeList() //it deletes all the "dupled" elements(or the more than 2 occurances per element)`

Usually I will define those in every class that I named above like this:

```
class MyArrayList<T>{
.
.
.
fun printList(){}
}
```

```
class MyLinkedList<T>{
.
.
.
fun printList(){}
}
```

```
class MyDoubleLinkedList<T>{
.
.
.
fun printList(){}
}
```

```
import edu.uni.lists.MyArrayList as MyList //or whatever other implementation I will interchange instead of MyArrayList

fun main() {
        val l1 = MyList<String> ()
        l1.create() //init
        if(l1.isEmpty())
            println("List is empty")

        l1.insert("11",l1.head())
        l1.insert("10",l1.head())
        l1.insert("9",l1.head())
        l1.insert("8",l1.head())
        l1.insert("7",l1.head())
        l1.insert("69",l1.head())
        l1.printList() //should print the whole list

}
```

Whatever the implementation I use, printList() will use only the data structure operators and nothing else.
The code of printList() is the same for every List Implementation.
I cannot place Services Function there!

I need to "move out" printlist()[and others services functions] from the List Implementations to another class or file.

How can I fullfill this request with Kotlin?

Thanks you all.

P.S. = I'm not an english native person, sorry if I'm not clear as you expect, feel free to ask more and I will reply!

Comment: Class names should always start with a capital letter in Kotlin and most other object oriented languages, FYI.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I have italian names of those class with capital letters, surely not keywords on kotlin.
I added "my" in a rush because I was afraid to confuse you with the kotlin built-in ones.
Corretected in the answer!
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create an [inteface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html) and extend it in all your clases

```
interface ListServices {
    fun printList()
}
class myArrayList<T> : ListServices {}
class myLinkedList<T> : ListServices {}
class myDoubleLinkedList<T> : ListServices {}
```

Or if you dont want to create a relationship between these classes, you can use [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

```
object ListServices {
    fun <T> myArrayList<T>.printList() {}
    fun <T> myLinkedList<T>.printList() {}
    fun <T> myDoubleLinkedList<T>.printList() {}
}
```

`T` is a [type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions), you must declare it before the name of the function. If your `print` function doesnt care about this type, you can use the [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

```
class myArrayList<T>(var foo: T)

object ListServices {
    fun myArrayList<*>.printList() {
        // here foo type is Any?
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try those and learn the differences.
The second solution it fits wilth my request.
Can you add more information about why I need to put <T> after fun ?
I don't get it.

Comment: Thanks you!
I don't know why but I ignored that part in [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) from Kotlin reference.